# Thymeleaf form submissions with parent object and child list

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I am building a web application with `spring boot 2.3.1` with `webflux`. As a part of the checkout process, I would like to post a from which will have an order and a list of LineItems. Idelaly, I would like to receive the Order object in controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ebooks/order/checkout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkOut(@ModelAttribute Order order, Model model)
```

The way I have it the LineItems List is not getting populated. How can make this work?

```
<form action="#" id="checkoutForm" method="post" th:action="@{/order/checkout}">
<input type="hidden" th:value="${cart.subTotal}"  id="subTotal" name="subTotal"/>

<th:block th:each="item : ${cart.items}">
<input type="hidden" th:value="${item.description}"  id="description" name="description"/>
<input type="hidden" th:value="${item.author}"  id="author" name="author"/>
<input type="hidden" th:value="${item.image}"  id="image" name="image"/>
<input type="hidden" th:value="${item.quantity}"  id="quantity" name="quantity"/>
<input type="hidden" th:value="${item.price}"  id="price" name="price"/>
</th:block>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light">Proceed to
checkout
</button>
</form>
```

classes:

```
public class Order {
    private String id;
    private String status;
    private String customerId;
    private BigDecimal subTotal;
    private List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();

    //gettert and setters
}

public class LineItem {
    String title;
    String description;
    String author;
    String image;
    int quantity;
    BigDecimal price;

    //gettert and setters
}
```

Comment: I was able to get tis working. I will post the code here soon:)